# Floating action button in andoidx library

Tags: android, floating-action-button, androidx

Hi is there anyone knows how to use the floating action button with andoidx library I think in android x library they replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xx.xx.xx'
```

by

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

but it's not helping any suggetion?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To use Floating action button in andoidx library use below `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

For more information check [**`Migrating to AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

### Complete example

> XML code

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/imgFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@android:color/white" />
```

### Notes

> `app:tint="@android:color/white"` is used to change the icon color of `FloatingActionButton`
>
> `app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"` is used to change `background` color of `FloatingActionButton`
>
> To use `FloatingActionButton`  inside activity or fragment we need to import `FloatingActionButton` like this

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: But how do you get the button to appear at the bottom right and not at the top left as it does with this code?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough didn't get you?

Comment: I tried the code above and the button appears, but it's at the top left of the screen.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough your button appears at top left of the screen because I have added `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf`, `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` , `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` just remove this from your code and apply constraint as per you requirement

Answer (score 9):

Now you can migrate to Android x and replace the xml with:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton ... />
```

Also in the gradle file add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

Answer (score -1):

To use Floating action button in androidx library use this implementation

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```